# Problem reading from file with arrays

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran95

On Fortran 95, I get an error message saying that itemarray(size) cannot be intent(out) which doesn't make any sense because you are reading itemarray from a file. How can I fix this error?

In this subroutine I am basically trying to read from a file and store values in arrays.

Below is the code for the subroutine I am referring to. Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

```
SUBROUTINE readItems(size,itemarray,priarray,quarray)

INTEGER:: iost=0, i=0
INTEGER, INTENT(OUT):: quarray(50)
INTEGER, INTENT(OUT):: size
REAL, INTENT(OUT):: priarray(50)
CHARACTER(20),INTENT(OUT)::itemarray(50)
CHARACTER(20)::namefiletoread

PRINT*,"Enter the name of file you would like to read: "
READ*,namefiletoread

OPEN(UNIT=77,FILE = namefiletoread, ACTION = "READ", STATUS="REWIND",IOSTAT=iost)
IF(iost>0)STOP "Problem opening the file!"

DO i=1, size
READ(77,'(A,F6.2,I8)',IOSTAT=iost), itemarray(i), priarray(i),quarray(i)
IF(iost<0)STOP
END DO


END SUBROUTINE
```

Comment: What compiler are you using (with which options), and what is the exact error message you get? Compiling with `gfortran -c -std=f95` only gives me a warning: "STATUS specifier in OPEN statement at (1) has invalid value 'REWIND'", which is correct, because you should use the specifier POSITION='REWIND'.

Comment: I'm using g95. I used status="rewind"

Comment: I think you're probably right. Instead of status="rewind" it should be position="rewind."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem could be with the variable "size".  It is declared intent(out), so clearly it doesn't come from the calling function, and it doesn't seem to be assigned anywhere before you start iterating over it.